# angular app web service http get response too late

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get

I have Angular CLI: 8.3.2, Node: 10.16.3 on win32 x64. I am trying out this angular frontend on a .net backend. The frontend has a web service to http.get a list of messages from the backend api, which is working fine, then the frontend would list the messages in the browser.

Below is the `getMessage` function of the WebService service component:

```
public async getMessage() {
await this.http.get<Message[]>(this.BASE_URL + '/Messages').subscribe(
        result => {
            if (result) {
                this.updateCollection(result);
            }
        },
        error => console.error(error)
    );
}
```

Below is the `MessagesComponent` that calls the webService to get the messages:

```
export class MessagesComponent {
    constructor(private webService: WebService) { 
        console.log("messages has " + webService.messages.length + "entries");
        webService.getMessage();
        console.log("messages has " + webService.messages.length + "entries");
    }
}
```

Both of these run with no error, and the web service `getMessages` function works fine as it can retrieve all of the messages, the problem is with the late invocation of the `getMessages` function. Even though it is called in the `MessagesComponent` constructor, it seems only actually does the retrieval **AFTER** the constructor, hence, rendering the page with no message to list. I've tried `getMessage` call without `async/await`, still the same behavior. So how to make sure it retrieves messages without the latency?

Comment: You don't need ` async/await ` for this, it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Return observable from service function.

```
public getMessage() {
    return this.http.get<Message[]>(this.BASE_URL + '/Messages')
        .pipe(
            tap(val => this.updateCollection(result)),
        );
}
```

In-state of calling the function inside the constructor, a good practice is to call inside ngOnInit.

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private webService: WebService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.webService.getMessage()
            .subscribe(
            result => {
               // do something
            },
            error => console.error(error)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I often let the service return the observable. Like this:

```
export class MessagesComponent {
    messages:Message[];
    constructor(private webService: WebService) { 
        webService.getMessage().subscribe(messages=>{
              this.messages = messages;
        });
    }
}
```

But in the end you should put it in the onInit method